# Use of function preg_replace to get the first characters after underscore (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to get all the first characters of a string with underscore.

for example:

```
Input: hello_this_is_test Output: HTIT
```

Is it possible to do this by regex and the replace function?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<?php
$string = 'hello_this_is_test';
$pattern = '...'; 
$replacement = '';
echo strtoupper(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));
?>
```

What I'm missing is the pattern. Anyone can help me through this please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative without regexes, but instead [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)ing then [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)ing back after only keeping the first letters using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$string = 'hello_this_is_test';

$string_parts = explode('_', $string);
$first_chars = array_map(static function ($part) { return $part[0] ?? ''; }, $string_parts);
echo strtoupper(implode('', $first_chars));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/bbSrH**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `preg_replace` with the following pattern:

```
(\w)[^_]*?(?:_|$)
```

and then replace with just the first capture group.

```
$string = 'hello_this_is_test';
$output = strtoupper(preg_replace("/(\w)[^_]*?(?:_|$)/", "$1", $string));
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
HTIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove from the second letter through to the next occurring underscore or the end if the string.

`\K` will match & release the first letter in a sequence, then keep the following characters to be removed.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/Do7m2)) ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkbIgt/1/))

```
$string = 'hello_this_is_test';
echo strtoupper(preg_replace('~[a-z]\K[^_]*_?~', '', $string));
```

Output:

```
HTIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all the characters that start words, using a positive lookbehind for either start of string or an `_`, and then uppercase the `implode` of all the matches:

```
$string = 'hello_this_is_test';
preg_match_all('/(?<=_|^)(.)/', $string, $matches);
echo strtoupper(implode('', $matches[1]));
```

Output:

```
HTIT
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fHeh5)

Comment: Note that this would match underscores themselves if they are allowed to be in a sequence (e.g. `__`), but it's easily fixable by changing `.` with `[^_]` (or anything more specific if needed).

Comment: @Jeto you're right - but I can only answer the question as asked. Definitely replacing `.` with `[a-zA-Z]` would ensure that the character started a "word" but without other sample data and some counter examples I've just tried to keep it simple.

Comment: Makes sense. Was just a "just-in-case" notice :)

Comment: @Jeto absolutely - you did make a good point and I've upvoted the comment so that (hopefully) anyone looking at this answer reads it too.